# Find the posterior distribution for an exponential prior and a Poisson likelihood

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

I have a prior  $\lambda \sim \exp(1)$ and a likelihood $X \sim poisson(\lambda)$, and I observed in a sample of $n=5$ a mean  of $3$. What is the posterior distribution of $\lambda$?

Here is my asnwer:

$f(x|\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$
$f(\lambda) = \theta e^{-\theta \lambda}, \theta = 1 => f(\lambda) = e^{-\lambda }$

So, the posterior:

$f(\lambda|x) \propto e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x} e^{-\lambda +(-\lambda)} = \lambda^{x}e^{-2 \lambda} $

This posterior is some known distribution (e.g. exponential)?

Comment: Since the standard (and standardized) procedure fully applies, you might want to explain what is causing you trouble here. (Furthermore, note that stricto sensu you asked no question.)

Comment: I have done the calculations but I don't know it my results are right. I would like to know if this posterior would be some know probability distribution (conjugate or not).

Comment: *I have done the calculations but I don't know it my results are right*... Then show them instead of leaving everybody in the blue.

Comment: Ok, I edited my post. Take a look please.

Comment: Which part of my answer is not the *standardized procedure* I alluded to in my first comment and, retrospectively, was causing you problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume one observed $x=(x_k)_{k\leqslant n}$, then $f(x\mid\lambda)=f(x_1\mid\lambda)\cdots f(x_n\mid\lambda)\propto\lambda^{|x|}\mathrm e^{-n\lambda}$ where $|x|=x_1+\cdots+x_n$ and $\propto$ refers to the fact that one omits multiplicative constants independent of $\lambda$. Thus, $f(\lambda\mid x)\propto f(\lambda)f(x\mid\lambda)\propto\lambda^{|x|}\mathrm e^{-(n+1)\lambda}$. To find the normalizing constant, recall that, for every positive $u$ and $v$,
$$
\int_0^\infty\lambda^{u-1}\mathrm e^{-v\lambda}\mathrm d\lambda=v^{-u}\Gamma(u),
$$
hence, finally,
$$
f(\lambda\mid x)=(n+1)^{-|x|-1}\,(|x|)!\,\lambda^{|x|}\mathrm e^{-(n+1)\lambda}.
$$
This is the gamma distribution with parameters $(n+1,|x|+1)$.

Comment: Please note that shape (alpha) = |x|+1 while rate (beta) = n+1, the order here is different from the arguments of gamma functions implemented in R.

Answer (score 1):

$f(\lambda|x) \propto \lambda^x \cdot \exp(-2\lambda)= \lambda^{(x+1)-1} \cdot \exp(-2\lambda)$.
This is a Gamma  density with parameters  $x+1,-2$, ie  Gamma($\lambda|x+1,-2$)

Comment: Since the exponential  is a special case of Gamma   ie Gamma(1,$\lambda$)  we  do have conjugacy.